# Mobile App: Hybrid logic, Native UI

Tags: javascript, android, ios, native, hybrid-mobile-app

as the title says, I'd like to combine the benefits of native UI with the advantages of hybrid app.
Internet is full of articles about React Native, Ionic, Native Script and so on, but they have all the common pattern: write in one language and the framework itself makes the conversion to native view components.

I want to avoid this process. I want to build my native UI and I want to call my hybrid component, written in Javascript or another language, and do all the logic stuff there.

A simple scenario (Android):

- I create a new Android `Activity` with one `button` (for eg. an "add" `button`).
- I tap on that `button`, which triggers the classic `onClick()` method
- Inside the `onClick()` method, I call my hybrid component which has the "add" function
- Inside my hybrid component, in the "app" function, I do all the stuff: http call/db query/nothing at all. Once I have a result, I call back the view to update it.

This pattern I have in mind is very similar to MVP. The only difference is that the presenter is shared between Android/iOS/Other SO

Once I heard that Spotify does exactly this, so I think that it is possible. But how?
Are there existing framework/libraries? Do I have to write by myself all the bridges between the different languages?

Thank you so much for your help/ideas

Comment: This is somewhat possible to do this with React Native, but it doesn't make sense to me to write the layout in native code. Write the View in React Native and then the logic in JS too, the View binds to a native component. If you're porting an existing app you will have to convert this component from native to React Native.

Comment: I already knew this solution, but it isn't what I want to achieve. What if Google/Apple release a new View? I have to spend time writing a new View in React. Or what if I create a new custom view? I have to spend time creating the custom view in native language, and then spend time writing the view in React. I'd like to avoid this redundance, writing UI only in native, and the hybrid part is responsible only for the logic

Comment: In that case take a look at Rhino https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino

Comment: @Cobolt thank you so much, it's a starting point. Now I need something similar for iOS

Comment: I am surprised there isn't more activity on this. I started using React Native and this is exactly what I've been wondering. @GiuseppeGiacoppo Did you learn something new since posting this question?

Comment: Hi @NoelDeMartin , yes I started working on Kotlin Multiplatform and that's the answer. The only problem is that you need to use multiplatform libraries in order to be compatible with iOS and Android. I'm using Ktor for http, SQLDelight for db